# oAuth2 Server POST /oauth2/token gets redirected

Tags: authentication-authorization

When my server tries to access /oauth2/token it gets a redirect.

It seems that the request never even makes it to the point where it can process the authorize_code since the server trying to access /oauth2/token is not authenticated.

This is not expected behaviour is it?  Is it possible another module is intercepting the authantication before it gets to the oauth2 server module?

Gerd.